# How to combine two queries from the same table using Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

From this sales table, I created 2 queries.

```
Sale::where(branch_id', 1)->select('*', DB::raw('SUM(amount) as amount))->groupBy('date')->get()

Sale::where(branch_id', 2)->select('*', DB::raw('SUM(amount) as amount))->groupBy('date')->get()
```

I want to combine  the two queries...

**to achieve this**

[image]

**Here's my sales table**

[image: actual sales table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for in raw SQL is this:

```
SELECT 
    `date`,
    SUM(IF(branch_id = 1, amount, 0)) as 'Branch 1',
    SUM(IF(branch_id = 2, amount, 0)) as 'Branch 2',
    SUM(amount) as 'Total'
FROM
    branches
WHERE
    branch_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
    `date`;
```

Unfortunately you can't do most of this with querybuilder, so you'll need to do it with `DB::raw()`, something like this:

```
Sale::whereIn(branch_id', [1,2])->
        select('date',
                DB::raw("
                    SUM(IF(branch_id = 1, amount, 0)) as 'Branch 1',
                    SUM(IF(branch_id = 2, amount, 0)) as 'Branch 2',
                    SUM(amount) as amount
                    ")
                )->groupBy('date')->get();
```

I haven't tested this in Laravel so it may be slightly off, but it should get you close.

[Sample fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3663d/3)

Answer (score 2):

Since they're both identical except for an integer, you could simply do this:

```
Sale::whereIn('branch_id', [1, 2])->...
```

... and let the rest of the query stay the same.

Comment: thanks for your response... but my expected outcome is that for each date... there's only 1 row... and I want to have the amount for branch1 and amount for branch 2...

Comment: Ah, you'll have to use a join and raw queries then.

Comment: I haven't actually done that in Laravel, so I'm not quite sure either. Sorry. I hope somebody else can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

DB::table('Sale')->whereIn('branch_id',[1,'2])->get();

Comment: for each day.. branch 1 will have 500 sales,, branch 2 will have 400 sales... I want to get something in my expected outcome